How to have the user input an int in the console and then depending on their input it would run a different block of code(JAVA)
The code below all works as it should except the if(choice = "1"). The program just stops working when I input for soloParty or multiParty in the console.
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OrderApp {
    //make sure to add menu and choose between a big group and solo group
    public void main(String[] args) {

        double burger; //number of burgers ordered
        double fries; //number of fries ordered
        double soda; // number of soda ordered
        double groupNumber;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //add menu

        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println("1 - Solo party");
        System.out.println("2 - Multiple Party");
        System.out.print("--->");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        //conditional
        if (choice = "1") {
            //Solo party 
            System.out.print("Enter the amount of burgers>>>:");
            burger = input.nextInt();
        } else {
            //multip party
            System.out.print("Enter Amount of Party Members");
            groupNumber = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}

Its specfically the if(choice = "1") and the }else{ it has a red line under it in VScode. I have no idea to how have the users input assign to an int and then have it run a different block of code depending on the input. I just need to know how to have the users input decide which code block to run.

choice = "1" tries to assign the string "1" to the int variable choice which is not possible. Did you mean choice == 1?

it is very often useful to read the error message in such cases (in this specific case, the error is very simple, easy to find, but it is always good to include such messages in questions here)

Please format and indent your code, also fix the compiling issue which are in the code snippet.  The code is not compiling, also why are you scanning an int then comparing it as a String ?
Please fix this

you reminded me when i was first introduced to programming. first,  if this is the main class to run your program , you missed out the word 'static' in your main class.
intead of

public  void main(String[] args) {

you should write

public static  void main(String[] args) {

second, comparison is double equal sign.
third,  you should use 1 instead of "1" because the datatype of your choice is int.
so you should use

if(choice == 1){

say hello to java world. cheers

Note: "comparison is double equal sign" for comparing primitives... objects are better compared using equals() (not the case in this specific question, but worth mentioning)
